# T-SQL Date Check between Parent and Child Tables using after triggers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

Here's an example:

We have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [TASK]
(
    [pk_TASK] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TASK_FROM_DATE] DATETIME NOT NULL,
    [TASK_TO_DATE]   DATETIME NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [JOB]
(
    [pk_JOB] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FK_TASK] INT NOT NULL,
    [JOB_FROM_DATE] DATETIME NOT NULL,
    [JOB_TO_DATE]   DATETIME NULL
)
```

I am aiming to encapsulate the logic in a trigger which should raise an error if the logic is violated.

The logic is: the job from and to dates should always fall between the task from and to dates.

If a user inserts a new JOB row and the dates are not between the TASk from and to date, then the trigger kicks in and raises an error.

If for instance, a user updates TASK from date which is later than the job from date (already existed) then error should be raised too.

Could you please advise on how I'd structure my trigger assuming that I will have plenty child tables.

Comment: You say "If a user inserts a new JOB row" but are you also wanting to enforce all operations (updates to JOB, updates to TASK) to prevent any temporal anomalies?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever no updates should be made to any table. if a user inserts new Job, the trigger will then look at the TASK using the fk_task then check if the dates in the job are not overlapping or out of the range. example Task has 01/09/16 to 15/09/16, if job is from 31/08/16 to 10/09/16 then error should be raised because the job from date is earlier than the parent from date

Comment: If you just want a straightforward trigger check 2nd answer below. However, I like @Damien_The_Unbeliever 's approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would actually create a structure where the constraints are enforced by real constraints, rather than relying on triggers. That way we ensure that the data is *correct*. We then hide this behind views that we use instead of the original tables, and then we do need the assistance of one small trigger just to set things up correctly.

First the new table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo._Tasks(
    pk_TASK [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    TASK_FROM_DATE DATETIME NOT NULL,
    TASK_TO_DATE   DATETIME NULL,
    _X_TASK_TO_DATE AS ISNULL(TASK_TO_DATE,CONVERT(datetime,'99991231',112)) persisted,
    constraint PK_Tasks PRIMARY KEY (pk_TASK),
    constraint CK_Tasks_NoTimeTravel CHECK (TASK_FROM_DATE < TASK_TO_DATE),
    constraint UQ_Tasks_XRef UNIQUE (pk_TASK,TASK_FROM_DATE,_X_TASK_TO_DATE)
)
go
CREATE TABLE dbo._Jobs(
    pk_JOB [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    FK_TASK INT NOT NULL,
    JOB_FROM_DATE DATETIME NOT NULL,
    JOB_TO_DATE   DATETIME NULL,
    _X_JOB_TO_DATE AS ISNULL(JOB_TO_DATE,CONVERT(datetime,'99991231',112)) persisted,
    _X_TASK_FROM_DATE DATETIME NOT NULL,
    _X_TASK_TO_DATE DATETIME NOT NULL,
    constraint PK_Jobs PRIMARY KEY (pk_JOB),
    constraint CK_Jobs_NoTimeTravel CHECK (JOB_FROM_DATE < JOB_TO_DATE),
    constraint FK_Jobs_Tasks FOREIGN KEY (FK_TASK) references _Tasks (pk_TASK),
    constraint FK_Jobs_Tasks_XRef FOREIGN KEY (FK_TASK,_X_TASK_FROM_DATE,_X_TASK_TO_DATE)
        references _Tasks (pk_Task,TASK_FROM_DATE,_X_TASK_TO_DATE)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    constraint CK_Jobs_Tasks_Enclosure CHECK (
        _X_TASK_FROM_DATE <= JOB_FROM_DATE AND
        _X_JOB_TO_DATE <= _X_TASK_TO_DATE
    )
)
```

Hopefully those do, "obviously", meet your requirements. It's impossible for a job to have dates outside of it's owning task. Next, we create the views:

```
create view dbo.TASK
with schemabinding
as
    select
        pk_TASK,
        TASK_FROM_DATE,
        TASK_TO_DATE
    from
        dbo._Tasks
go
create view dbo.JOB
with schemabinding
as
    select
        pk_JOB,
        FK_TASK,
        JOB_FROM_DATE,
        JOB_TO_DATE
    from
        dbo._Jobs
```

Nothing surprising here, hopefully. It's these views that your users now interact with, and they look exactly like the original tables. But I did mention a trigger:

```
create trigger T_JOB_I
on dbo.JOB
instead of insert
as
    insert into dbo._Jobs (FK_TASK,JOB_FROM_DATE,JOB_TO_DATE,_X_TASK_FROM_DATE,_X_TASK_TO_DATE)
    select i.FK_TASK,i.JOB_FROM_DATE,i.JOB_TO_DATE,t.TASK_FROM_DATE,t._X_TASK_TO_DATE
    from inserted i
            inner join
        dbo._Tasks t
            on
                i.FK_TASK = t.pk_TASK
```

We need this so that the cross-referencing columns which allow us to write our `CHECK` constraint get successfully populated initially. The `CASCADE` on the foreign key constraint ensures that they're updated as appropriate and ensure that no-one can edit a task later and make the data violate any constraints.

Comment: This is one clever way of doing it, bravo! however I don't see it scalable. meaning if we have Task as parent, Job as child of Task and event as child of Job then I'd assume that event table will have extra unnecessary columns which are used only for date checks

Comment: @user2351804 - if you've already checked that a job fits within the task, then you only need to copy the job columns down into the event. Transitively, you know that if the event fits within the job then it must also fit within the task. So essentially `_Events` would be a repeat of the `_Jobs` table with jobs being used where tasks were originally.

Comment: It makes sense, and I personally think it's better handled using constraint than triggers. I forgot to add: there will be cases when the to date is null, means that the task has an open date. if to date is null also means that the date is in the future. How can I go about implementing this in the constraint. Thanks a lot Damien

Comment: @user2351804 - that's why I've treated nulls as being the same as 31st December 9999 (and why I'm using computed columns on the from dates) (that, and we need non-null columns to make the foreign keys works anyway)

Answer (score 0):

See if this would work:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgCheckDateRange ON dbo.JOB INSTEAD OF UPDATE,INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @operation AS CHAR(1)

    -- Identifies the operation type
    SET @operation = 'N'
    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM INSERTED) AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED) 
        SET @operation = 'U'
    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM inserted) AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED) 
        SET @operation = 'I'

    IF @operation = 'U' or @operation = 'I'
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS(
            SELECT 1 FROM 
            INSERTED  I
            JOIN TASK T ON I.FK_TASK = T.pk_TASK
            WHERE i.JOB_FROM_DATE < t.TASK_FROM_DATE or
                  i.JOB_TO_DATE > T.TASK_TO_DATE
        )
        BEGIN
            THROW 51000, 'DATE IS OUTSIDE OF TASK RANGE.', 1;  
        END
    END

    -- Update
    IF @operation = 'U' 
    BEGIN 
        -- Updates the original
        UPDATE dbo.JOB
        SET FK_TASK = 80,
            JOB_FROM_DATE = I.JOB_FROM_DATE,
            JOB_TO_DATE = I.JOB_TO_DATE
        FROM dbo.JOB J
        INNER JOIN INSERTED I
            ON J.pk_JOB = I.pk_JOB              
    END 
    --- Insert
    ELSE IF @operation = 'I' 
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.JOB
                ( FK_TASK, JOB_FROM_DATE, JOB_TO_DATE )
        SELECT FK_TASK, JOB_FROM_DATE, JOB_TO_DATE 
        FROM INSERTED

    END 
END
```